# Using query parameter in Access report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a very basic access database where a query returns the sales
made within a set start date and a set end date.

The dates are set with two pop up boxes for the user to enter, first
the start date, and then the end date.

I have a report running off the back of this.

How can I (using VBA) get at these dates then display them on the
report - ie. the report says "Sales for Period:" and then shows the
"from date" and the "to date" that the user input.

Comment: is this homework? also, you should be able to find this answer on google

Comment: it's a function I would like to add to an assignment at college, so kind of yes. Can't find an answer on google at my level unfortunately.

Comment: You can google anything instead of coming to SO-what's the point? Homework questions are OK when the user has part of the solution or made an attempt.

Answer (score 2):

You may find [this tutorial](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA011170771033.aspx) helpful. It shows how to use a form to capture parameters for queries and reports and access the parameter values in VBA.

Comment: That's a really nice tutorial -- much better than the usual MS-hosted stuff.